# Null-safe equals comparison

Tags: sql, sqlite, null, equality

SQLite 3.27:

Is there a way to write an expression where comparing a `null` to a `null` would evaluate to true?

For example:

```
with data (a,b) as (
values
(1,1),
(1,null),
(null,null)
)

select
  *
from
  data
where
  a = b
```

But the result would be:

```
     a       b
------  ------
     1       1
(null)  (null)
```

Instead of:

```
     a       b
------  ------
     1       1
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=d4c4b8778cbf8b3e52ee53a490d69b9f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the answer is **yes**.

Use `IS` instead of `=`:

```
with data (a,b) as (
values
(1,1),
(1,null),
(null,null)
)

select
  *
from
  data
where
  a is b
```

Result:

```
     a       b
------  ------
     1       1
(null)  (null)
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=ac1709d5ef5fd1009097827dbdb3dd30)

---

Related:

- [Can I use… IS NOT DISTINCT FROM (null-safe equals comparison)](https://modern-sql.com/caniuse/is-not-distinct-from)
- [Can I use… is (binary comparison)](https://modern-sql.com/caniuse/is_(binary_compariso))

I don't have a newer version of SQLite to test in. But it's possible the `is` syntax doesn't work in newer versions. Maybe only the `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` syntax works in newer versions of SQLite.